# PowerShell - environment vars - differentiating between user and system vars

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

How can I display environment variables in PowerShell, and be able to distinguish between which ones are "user" vars and which ones are "system" vars?

Answer (score 3):

Not a powershell pro, but at worst, you could go fish around in the registry to see whether the vars you're interested in are showing up there.  Inside a given session, I'm not really sure there's any distinction between user/sys vars other than the registry storage location...

Pertinent keys are:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

Comment: Correct: in process there is no distinction. And of course `PATH` is a combination of system and user settings so as set is neither.

Answer (score 0):

To find out within PowerShell:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'

Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKCU\Environment'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PowerShell has access to the .NET Framework, you could use

> [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::**Machine**)
>   [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::**Process**)
>   [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::**User**)